# Android, I want to change a word in a textview

Tags: android, textview, arrays

I have a string-array with multiple sentences like

Hi ***, I wanted to thank you blah blah....

Hey ***, don't forget to call me....

and so on...

I have a button that generates random phrases (i'm ok with that)

what i want to do is when the user click the button it should replace the *** by the actual name of the person.

How do you change specific character from a string-array list in the string.xml ?

Thank you

This is my actual code i'm stuck at basically changing the * by the name:

```
Button generate;
EditText friendName;
TextView cannedPhrase;
String[] randomPhrase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeWidgets();
}

private void initializeWidgets() {
    // Initializes, button, EditText and TextView

    generate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGenerate);
    friendName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextFriendsName);
    cannedPhrase = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewRandomPhrase);
    randomPhrase = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.canned_phrases);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onGenerate(View V){

    String randomStr = randomPhrase[new Random().nextInt(randomPhrase.length)];
    String friend = friendName.getText().toString();
    cannedPhrase.setText(randomStr);

}
```

}

Comment: This is really 3 questions. How do you get the data from the text view, how do you set it, and how do you change a character in a string. See what you can figure out for those 3 parts, and let us know what your progress is on working on them, and where you are having problems.

Comment: look at my code above

Comment: why the downvotes ? what's wrong with my question ?

Comment: People generally like well defined questions, trying to address a specific part of a problem. This seems like a "tell me how to do my work for me" problem, which people around here generally don't like. Your edit helps considerably, I would focus on the fact that you are trying to change all of the * characters to a word in a string, and ignore everything else out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `strings.xml` replace `*` with a string placeholder, `%s`:

```
<string-array name="canned_phrases">
   <item>"Hi %s, I wanted to thank you blah blah...."</item>
   <item>"Hey %s, don't forget to call me...."</item>
</string-array>
```

In your code, use [`String#format(String, Object...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

`cannedPhrase.setText(String.format(randomStr, friend))`

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to replace a set character with your name, then you can call String's replace method like so in your onGenerate method:

```
String randomStr = ...
String friend = ...
randomStr = randomStr.replace("*", friend);
cannedPhrase.setText(randomStr);
```

Comment: Considering capturing the result of `replace()`